# how to parametrize url in put requests using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, python-requests

I am trying to send parameterized url in put request using python.
One of my function "getipaddress()" is returning the device ip address as 192.168.72.31

Code:

```
import requests
ips= getipaddress()
URL = "https://%s/UDW/Command?entry=eprint.register" % ips
r = requests.put(url=URL,data=data, verify=False)
print r.status_code
```

Getting error : 405 error (Method Not Allowed response status code).

Comment: seems like the controller doesn't support "PUT" method, try to use `requests.get(url=URL,data=data, verify=False)`

Comment: This isn't related to the fact you are formatting the string (try `requests.put(url="https://192.168.72.31/UDW/Command?entry=eprint.register",data=data, verify=False)` Are you sure you are allowed to use PUT with that url?

Answer (score 0):

As per inputs from @Ami Hollander and @DeepSpace I have figured out that put request is not supported. Trying with get request, I am able to get the response

```
Code :
      ips = getipaddress()   # returns device ip:192.168.72.31
      url = "https://%s/UDW/Command?entry=eprint.register" % ips  
      requests.get(url=URL,verify=False)

Output :
        {
          "state": 200,
          "eprint_reg_state": "registering"
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess your server doesn't accept PUT requests

in Flask : `@app.route('/your_route', methods=['PUT'])`

in Django : doesn't support PUT requests, you'll need to use http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Yep. This assumption was already in comments. Can you add more info regarding this issue?

Comment: Sorry didn't took time to read the comments. I can add more info if @Sum would like to share his backend code and framework used